# custom navigation bar?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a custom navigation bar that looks like this:
[image: navigation image]

I set it as the background image of the navigation bar.  But how do I implement the buttons? I want to be able to click on the individual text and have an action happen

Could I possibly add a gesture recognizer over each word on the image?

Answer (score 0):

Put an invisible button on the toolbar for each place you want to have a button. If you want this to look and behave exactly like a normal toolbar, however, you can't have the buttons be part of the background image. It's very easy to make a toolbar that looks like what you have in IB.

[image]

It took longer to upload this to imgur than it did to make it!